# Reading a PDF file using PyPDF2 returns unreadable string in Python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, encoding, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF2 to read a PDF:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

print(reader.is_encrypted)  # prints False

page = reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
```

The text is printed as "<RX\x03DUH\x03 FXUUHQW..."

I tried to encode it with different types of encoding ('utf_8', 'utf_16', 'ascii' and more) but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to use PdfFileReader directly with the filepath ? `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(r'pathToMyFile')`

Comment: Related (unanswered) [*How to parsing text for Vietnamese pdf with python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952664/)

Comment: I took the freedom to replace the deprecated syntax by the new PyPDF2 syntax + remove unnecessary details. Some important details are missing: (1) What is the output of `import PyPDF2; print(PyPDF2.__version__)`? (2) Can you share the PDF? (3) Which language has the content of the PDF? Can you maybe share the beginning of the text you would expect?

Comment: Is the issue just occurring with python 3.9?